# Issues with inserting data with ef core on migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I am trying to write in my own bit of code to the ef core migration Up method to insert some static data into a table.  In short I want to do this. INSERT INTO file_type (filetypeid, filetype) VALUES (10, 'Output File');

Code in migration

```
        migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            "file_type",
            new string[] { "filetypeid", "filetype" },
            new string[] { "integer", "varchar" },
            new object[] { "10", "Output File" });
```

When I use the above code I get

The store type 'integer' used for the column 'file_type.filetypeid' in a migration data operation is not supported by the current provider.

If I leave out the data type argument (3) I get

There is no entity type mapped to the table 'file_type' used in a data operation. Either add the corresponding entity type to the model or specify the column types in the data operation.

Model

```
[Table("file_type")]
public class FileType
{
    [Key]
    [Column("filetypeid")]
    public int FileTypeId { get; set; }
    [Column("filetype")]
    public string FileTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Reference I am using
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.insertdata?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Migrations_MigrationBuilder_InsertData_System_String_System_String___System_String___System_Object___System_String_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using. Thanks @Farzan for the help.

`migrationBuilder.Sql("INSERT INTO file_type (filetypeid, filetype) VALUES (10, 'Output File');", false);`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the provider you are using with `ef core`, you will want to specify the corresponding data type value for your provider. For example: use `int` for SQL Server. More info: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp

Comment: I am using Ngpsql for postgres and I have tried int numeric and integer

Comment: Try specifying the column's data type in annotation. i.e. `Column[Name="filetypeid", TypeName="integer"]`. Here is more info: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Did not work. I am getting the same error.